# Zonal histogram processing and invalid geometries

Tags: geometry, histogram

In QGIS 3.4, when  I try to get a zonal histogram it returns an error related to invalid geometries in the vetor layer.
I've fixed geometries and, despite the layer have seemingly only valid geometries (as showed in the check geometry results), the "zonal histogram" algorithm keeps in the "calculating field" stage, without progress.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, try this, just go to the process toolbox, then vector geometry and run Fix geometries on the input layer
[image]

This will generate a new layer, corrected, with which you will work

Comment: Hi Luis, the problem  still persists, even after fix geometries. The algorithm remains processing, "endlessly".